# How to "Select" a correct user answer based on a random q.uestion generated

Tags: python

```
num1 = random.randint(1,20)
num2 = random.randint(1,20)
question = ["Bigger" , "Smaller"]
questiondecide = random.choice(question))
if questiondecide == "Higher":
userAnswer=input("Please find the Higher value between" + num1 "and" + 
num2)
elif questiondecide == "Lower":
userAnswer=input("Please find the Lower value between" + num1 "and" + 
num2)
```

I'm stuck on this point, I'm trying to figure out a way that if the code chooses Bigger/smaller
, the code will identify the bigger/smaller number generated and thus require the user to input the answer based on the question, but how do I identify if num1 or num2 is bigger or smaller and thus write a condition to award the user a point for answering correctly?

Basically want this: (Possible algorithm)

```
if set of numbers generated is higher
require user to input bigger number
userMarks = userMarks + 1
```

and so on if smaller number is asked, how do I write this down in Python?

Comment: You forgot to add the part, where you actually atempt to use python to get the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from random import randint

num1 = random.randint(1,20)
num2 = random.randint(1,20)

question = ["Bigger" , "Smaller"]
questiondecide = random.choice(question)


biggest = max(num1, num2)
smallest = min(num1, num2)

if questiondecide == "Bigger":
    userAnswer = input("Please find the Higher value between " + str(num1) + " and " + str(num2) + ":" + "\n")
print(biggest)
if userAnswer == biggest:
    print("This is the biggest number")
    print("and you have chosen the bigger number!")
elif userAnswer == smallest:
    print("This is the smallest number")
    print("but you have not chosen the bigger number!")

elif questiondecide == "Smaller":
   userAnswer = input("Please find the Lower value between " + str(num1) + " and " + str(num2) + ":" + "\n")
if userAnswer == biggest:
    print("This is the biggest number")
    print("but you have not chosen the smaller number!")
elif userAnswer == smallest:
    print("This is the smallest number")
    print("and you have chosen the smaller number!")
```

Hope this helps! Have any questions ask away!

Comment: Thank you! The code you written with a few minor changes has worked, thanks!

Comment: Oops, I seem to be experiencing a hiccup

Comment: The code does work, but when I input the answer, for example if it's asking for higher value between 78 and 10, I type 78, but nothing else prints, just the number

Comment: By the way before you were a little early to state that this was the correct answer, check thoroughly! Only tick it once you've got what you desired! Anyway good luck with it!